# Kinetic JS func is not return object

Tags: javascript

```
function create(x,y,imagePath,imageWidth,imageHeight) {

return new Kinetic.QImage({
        x: x,
        y: y,
        image: images.Grid,
        width: imageWidth,
        height: imageHeight,
});

}


var a = create(100,100,images.Grid,96,96);
```

Why didn't this work?

Comment: please give details of your error when asking about an error. It makes the lives of those nice people who would like to help you easier.

Comment: why do you by 'why didn't this work'? You got an error? No error but nothing happened? etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are getting an error about an undefined variable called images...

Do this rather:

```
function create(x,y,images,imageWidth,imageHeight) {

return new Kinetic.QImage({
    x: x,
    y: y,
    image: images.Grid,
    width: imageWidth,
    height: imageHeight,
});

}


var a = create(100,100,images,96,96);
```